# Issue while installing a managed package in a production org

Tags: managed-package, install

I have the standard Activity component in one of my custom object's page layout which has 3 activities (New Event, New Task , Log a call)in it. I created the 2GP and during installation of the package in a production org, i am getting this below error :-

```
(customObjectName-CustomObjectName Layout) In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named <namespace>__NewEvent found...
```

Has anyone faced this issue before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the "NewEvent" QuickAction metadata type to the 2GP

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution worked.